# Portfolio optimisation in R - group ratio constraints

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, portfolio, nonlinear-optimization

Let's say we have a simple long-only problem with four assets and several constraints. Below is how I would normally optimise portfolio weights with some basic constraints, such as weights sum to 1, no short selling and no leverage.

```
# set the covariance matrix:

cov <- cbind(c(0.1486, 0.0778, -0.0240, -0.0154), 
             c(0.0778, 0.1170, 0.0066, 0.0029), 
             c(-0.0240, 0.0066, 0.0444, 0.0193), 
             c(-0.0154, 0.0029, 0.0193, 0.0148)
)

# expected returns:

dvec <- c(0.0308, 0.0269, 0.0145, 0.0130)

# constraints:
# 1) weights to sum to 1
# 2) minimum weight for each asset = 0
# 3) maximum weight for each asset = 1

Amat <- cbind(c(1, 1, 1, 1), diag(1,4,4), diag(-1,4,4))
bvec <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1)
meq = 1

# The solution for portfolio weights is as follows:
round(solve.QP(cov, dvec=dvec, Amat=Amat, bvec=bvec, meq=meq)$solution,4)
```

Now, I would like to add a constraint that the first asset is less or equal than 60% of the *first three assets* taken together. How could I add this constraint to the above portfolio? It is easy to set the upper bound for an asset as a percentage of the overall portfolio, but I don't know how to set the upper bound for an asset as a percentage of a certain *group* of assets.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please note MATLAB does have this functionality but it is not clear which solver is used and how it is set up: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/finance/working-with-group-ratio-constraints-using-portfolio-object.html

Comment: What is the problem with `x(1) <= 0.6*(x(1)+x(2)+x(3))` ?

Comment: Erwin, that's exactly what I want to do. How do I express that in Amat and bvec?

Comment: Rewrite as `-0.4x1+0.6x2+0.6x3>=0` and add a row to Amat and add a zero to bvec. What is the problem here?

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer I was looking for and it works.